# Why we say that an arbitrary element of $(Z, +)$ is of infinite order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Why we say that an arbitrary non-identity element of $(Z, +)$  is of infinite order? I know it is cyclic, because it is possible to express all elements as multiples (repeated additions) of the element $1$.

The order of an element is defined as how many times we need to combine it with itself until we obtain the identity.

We say that an arbitrary element of $(Z, +)$ have infinite order but why we don't just say it is of *no order* because in this case no matter how many times we combine an element with itself, we can't obtain identity?

Comment: Another way to define the "order" of a group element $g\in G$ is by the *size* (cardinality) of the (cyclic) subgroup generated by that element, $\langle g \rangle$.  Thus the size of a cyclic subgroup, when the given element is not of finite order, is infinite.

Comment: Another reason is the group is supposed to be closed under the operation $+$. So $\alpha=2+2+2+ \dotsb$ should be an element of $\Bbb{Z}$. If we don't define the concept of "infinite" order, then what will this element $\alpha$ be ?

Comment: The comment of @hardmath is consistent with another group-theoretic usage of "order", namely that the [order of a group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)) is equal to the cardinality of the group. So now you can say that the order of a cyclic group is equal to the order of any of its generators.